# git setup for multiple repos on same server

Tags: git, ssh, github, public-key

Probably a simple question, but I am at a loss here...

In github one can add a deployment key for each repository which only gives access to that single repository.

But for one client I have two projects managed with git on the same server (project A and project B). If I use the public key for project A, github tells me I cant use it as a deployment key for project B and vice versa.

How can I create another public key and setup git to use one key for project A and the other one for project B?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The `ssh` way to do this would be using `~/.ssh/config`, creating a hostname alias and accessing github with different hostnames for both projects. I have no idea whether there is a `git config` (or `git remote`) way too.

```
Host a.github.com
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/project-a-id_rsa

Host b.github.com
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/project-b-id_rsa
```

Then use `a.github.com:user/project-a.git` or `b.github.com:user/project-b.git` (or similar) as your repository URLs.

Comment: Thank you very much, sounds good! Means I would clone my project repositories on the clients server again with the a.github.com/b.github.com urls and before that store the public key as repository key in my github account, right? I´ll give it a try as soon as I can.

Comment: I think you would not need to clone them again, if you already have them there - you can change the remote repository url with `git remote`.

Comment: That worked exactly the way you described. Great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This workaround worked for me, thanks. But why does GitHub have this limitation in the first place? Does anyone know?

Comment: This workaround worked for me for multiple different deploy keys on same server with multiple repositories. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Let's say `alice` is a github.com user, with 2 or more private repositories `repoN`.
For this example we'll work with just two repositories named `repo1` and `repo2`

`https://github.com/alice/repo1`

`https://github.com/alice/repo2`

You need to be to pull from these repositories without entering a passwords probably on a server, or on multiple servers.
You want to perform `git pull origin master` for example, and you want this to happen without asking for a password.

You don't like dealing with ssh-agent, you have discovered (or you're discovering now) about `~/.ssh/config` a file that let's your ssh client know what private key to use depending on Hostname and username, with a simple configuration entry that looks like this:

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/alice/.ssh/alice_github.id_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

So you went ahead and created your `(alice_github.id_rsa, alice_github.id_rsa.pub)` keypair, you then also went to your repository's `.git/config` file and you modified the url of your remote `origin` to be something like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = "ssh://git@github.com/alice/repo1.git"
```

And finally you went to the repository `Settings > Deploy keys` section and added the contents of `alice_github.id_rsa.pub`

At this point you could do your `git pull origin master` without entering a password without issue.

#### but what about the second repository?

So your instinct will be to grab that key and add it to `repo2`'s Deploy keys, but github.com will error out and tell you that the key is already being used.

Now you go and generate another key (using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "alice@alice.com"` without passwords of course), and so that this doesn't become a mess, you will now name your keys like this:

- `repo1` keypair: `(repo1.alice_github.id_rsa, repo1.alice_github.id_rsa.pub)`
- `repo2` keypair: `(repo2.alice_github.id_rsa, repo2.alice_github.id_rsa.pub)`

You will now put the new public key on `repo2`'s Deploy keys configuration at github.com, but now you have an ssh problem to deal with.

#### How can ssh tell which key to use if the repositories are hosted on the same `github.com` domain?

Your `.ssh/config` file points to `github.com` and it doesn't know which key to use when it's time to do the pull.

So I found a trick with github.com. You can tell your ssh client that each repository lives in a different github.com subdomain, in these cases, they will be `repo1.github.com` and `repo2.github.com`

So first thing is editing the `.git/config` files on your repo clones, so they look like this instead:

For repo1

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = "ssh://git@repo1.github.com/alice/repo1.git"
```

For repo2

[remote "origin"]
        url = "ssh://git@repo2.github.com/alice/repo2.git"

And then, on your `.ssh/config` file, now you will be able to enter a configuration for each subdomain :)

```
Host repo1.github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/alice/.ssh/repo1.alice_github.id_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host repo2.github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/alice/.ssh/repo2.alice_github.id_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Now you are able to `git pull origin master` without entering any passwords from both repositories.

If you have multiple machines, you could copy the keys to each of the machines and reuse them, but I'd advise doing the leg work to generate 1 key per machine and repo. You will have a lot more keys to handle, but you will be less vulnerable if one gets compromised.

Comment: I think your answer is great. But the way its written is very confusing. You might want to edit it.